# Android Studio - How to handle error regarding xml files

Tags: xml, android-studio, compiler-errors

A few days ago, I started learning Kotlin language and i'm currently struggling with an issue with Android Studio. I have an XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <Folder title="title">
        <Album title="author">
            <Song title="title" author="author">lyrics</Song>
        </Album>
    </Folder>
</resources>
```

And when I try to run the project, I get the following error:

```
Can't determine type for tag '<resources>
    <Fold title="title">
        <Album title="author">
            <Song title="title" author="author">lyrics</Song>
        </Album>
    </Fold>
</resources>'
```

The xml file is in res/values/

Do you know a way to solve this issue? (and above all, what does it mean?)

Comment: You can't put custom XML in resources like that. Any file with a root tag of `<resources>` expects certain components only. Instead, you could create a `res/xml/` directory, if there isn't one already, and put your XML file under that. You would access it by using `getResources().getXml(R.xml.whatever_your_file_name)`, which returns an `XmlResourceParser` that you can loop over. Alternatively, if you'd rather access it as plain text, you can put it in `assets/`, and use `getAssets().open("whatever_your_file_name.xml")` to get an `InputStream`.

Comment: Okay thank you for this answer! I'll do it right away!

Comment: To use getRessources(), do I have to import any library?

Comment: No, but it's an instance method on `Context`, so you need one of those; e.g., an `Activity`, a `Service`, etc. If you are in one of those classes, in a non-`static` method, you can just call `getResources()` directly. Otherwise, you'll have to somehow get a `Context` instance to wherever you're trying to do that; e.g., via a method or constructor parameter.